.NET 8 Memory Leak Testing Visible in Windows Task Manager?
c# console app on Windows 11 (target OS is Win Server 2019) makes 1000 instances of this class in an array, and after 30 seconds disposes of them. The memory increase is not visible in the Windows Task Manager. What would be a good way to make memory allocation/deallocation visible? Goal is to simulate high memory usage in a cloud environment so autoscaling happens when a memory threshold is reached.
public class memc : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IntPtr _bu;

    public memc()
    {
        _bu = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(5120000);
        byte[] dataToWrite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bu");
        Marshal.Copy(dataToWrite, 0, _bu, dataToWrite.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_bu);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

Thanks.

Where and how is this called? Why not just create an ordinary very large array instead of these acrobatics?

Just put your code in a console app and instantiated 1000 instances of memc and memory went up in Task Manager.

@Fildor Called console app main[] makes a 1000-element array of this, waits 60 seconds, and disposes array elements in a Finally block. Task manager showed OS zero memory change during run of console app  so I could not understand if .NET runtime was masking from the OS. OS needs to detect/show memory usage so autoscaling of VMs can be triggered.

Check the resulting code for whether the creating of the array has been "optimized" away. If it has, you will need to either actually do something with the array of switch off optimization.
